# Data Reviewer - how to check for polygon must be covered by line?

Tags: arcgis-10.4, data-reviewer

I am a new Data Reviewer user and have spent too much time trying to solve this so I knew it was time to ask for help. I have a polygon layer and a line layer.

They are in different feature datasets, so topology won't work here. I need the Data Reviewer equivalent to polygon must be covered by line so that I can find where the polygon and line are not lined up properly.

I've been trying different options in Geometry on Geometry but nothing has worked.

Can anybody suggest something to try, or point me to an online resource, as I haven't found anything relevant.